# How to use array as an object attribute in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, attributes

I have created a class with an array attribute. I have also created an array of objects. I wish to know how can I call access the array elements of a particular object?

The class is:

```
public class node
{
    public int node_num;
    public int total_weight;
    public int[] neighbors;

     node(int num, int weight,int neigh[])
    {
        this.node_num = num;     //node number      
        this.total_weight = weight;   //row total
        this.neighbors=neigh;     //adjacent nodes
    }       
}
```

My main function is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int n=5;
    int temp1,temp2;
        int adj_mat[][]= {{0,4,0,0,10},{4,0,6,2,0},{0,6,0,4,0},{0,2,4,0,0},{10,0,0,0,0}};     //populating the weighted adjacency matrix


        int i=0, j=0;
        int n1[]=new int[n];

        cluster cluster1=new cluster();

        node nodes[] = new node[n];

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
             int sum=0,k=0;

                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {                   
                    if(adj_mat[i][j]!=0)
                    {
                        sum= sum+adj_mat[i][j];  
                        n1[k]=j+1;
                        k=k+1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        n1[k]=0;
                        k=k+1;
                    }
                }
                        nodes[i]=cluster1.new node(i+1,sum,n1);
            }
        int m;
         for(i=0;i<n;i++)
         {   
             System.out.print("\nNeighbor of "+nodes[i].node_num +" is ");
                for(m=0;m<5;m++)
                {
                    System.out.print(nodes[i].neighbors[m]+",");
                }
         }
```

The expected output is:

Neighbor of 1 is 0,2,0,0,5,

Neighbor of 2 is 1,0,3,4,0,

Neighbor of 3 is 0,2,0,4,0,

Neighbor of 4 is 0,2,3,0,0,

Neighbor of 5 is 1,0,0,0,0,

The current output is:

Neighbor of 1 is 1,0,0,0,0,

Neighbor of 2 is 1,0,0,0,0,

Neighbor of 3 is 1,0,0,0,0,

Neighbor of 4 is 1,0,0,0,0,

Neighbor of 5 is 1,0,0,0,0,

Comment: Can you show the entire code?  I don't see your ever initializing the `neighbors` array, and that would be a problem right there.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it seems is passed on his constructor  `this.neighbors=neigh`

Comment: This code above won't produce the output you describe (or indeed, any output other than an error message). In your real code, perhaps you're reusing the array you pass into the `node` constructor or similar, but we can't help you with only the information currently in the question. (Side note: While you can do anything you like in your own code, when asking for help, please follow standard naming conventions. Class names should be initially-capped, so `Node`, not `node`.)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry. I will post a separate question with the entire code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry Sir. I am new to Stack Overflow. I will follow the standards from now on. Thank you.

Comment: @AmudhanManisekaran - No need for a separate question, just edit this one to add the [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Done sir.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class node
 {
        public int node_num;
        public int[] neighbors;

        node(int num, int neigh[])
        {
            this.node_num = num;
            this.neighbors=neigh;
        }   
    public int getNode_num(){
         return node_num;
     }
    public int[] getNeighbors(){
    return neighbors;
    }


}




node nodes[] = new node[n];     

for(i=0;i<nodes.length();i++)
         {

                for(m=0;m<nodes[i].getNeighbors().length();m++)
                {
                    System.out.print(neighbors[m]+",");
                }


         }
```

Comment: Thank you sir. But the same error persists. I will post a separate question with the entire code.

Comment: maybe u should push some objects in ur table